Boost R-Tree with custom distance function for kNN
For days I have been trying to figure out how to pass a custom distance function to boost R-Tree for k-nearest neighbors queries.
I have a huge number of linestrings and polygons. I embed both into boost bounding box and create a R-Tree over the bounding boxes:
using RTreeValue = std::pair<BoostBox, FeatureId>;

For spatial queries (i.e. contains, covers, intersects etc.) this works very well and fast:
rtree.query(boost::geometry::index::intersects(query_shape), custom_filter);

the second argument is a custom predicate filtering out objects with bounding boxes intersecting the query shape but where the actual geometry (linestring, polygon) not intersecting it (based on the FeatureId).
The problem comes with k-nearest neighbors search. I would like to use the same index (R-Tree) over bounding boxes rather than using the actual geometry. The reason is that the linestrings and polygons have large number of points which could significantly slow down the queries. Second reason is a restricted memory: I don't have enough memory (it's part of a complex system) to create another index over the actual geometry.
So, I have an existing index over the bounding boxes (RTreeValue). When I start a bgi::nearest query
std::vector<RTreeValue> results;
rtree.query(boost::geometry::index::nearest(point, k), custom_evaluation(results));

the vast majority of results are incorrect. The reason is that some bounding boxes can intersect each other (distance = 0) but their actual geometries could be far apart.
The second argument in the query call is called only as many times, as the number of searched neighbors is and it is called after distance between two objects has been calculated (so it could be used only for filtering out objects from final results).
I have been experimenting with boost::geometry::indexable but have not achieved the goal: it's meant to provide an indexable geometry from input objects to build the R-Tree (the boost bounding box is currently indexable).
Any ideas, how to pass a custom distance function to the k-nearest neighbors search, which would compute real distance based on FeatureId?

You can combine nearest (on box boundaries) with a custom predicate. The nearest will return in order or increasing distance, so when the box-distance exceeds your threshold you stop iterating.

@sehe Thank you for the idea, however the custom predicate only controls whether value should be included in the results during the query. It does not stop the tree traversal, if you return false. The traversal stops only if the query found k nearest objects, based on the bounding box distance.
The custom predicate definitely helps filtering out objects where the true distance (to the actual object) is larger than the k-th item but unfortunately it does not provide a guarantee that the traversal won't miss a branch of the tree with closer objects.

If you iterate manually, instead of using the range adaptor or output-iterator processor interface, you can just stop. Alternative, you may throw an exception for flow control.

@sehe I realized that calculating the true distance to an actual object inside the query is making the search very slow (the polylines and polygons can have a lot of points). Instead, I start simple k-nearest search over the bounding boxes. Then I get the maximum true distance to the k-th found neighbor and use this distance for a subsequent range query (again over bounding boxes). The range query returns a superset of the final k-nearest neighbors. Because both queries work over bounding boxes, they turned out much faster than the customized nearest query.

That makes sense. It might even make sense to answer your own question, unless something makes that approach unusable

As mentioned in the comments, calculating distance of the query point to the actual objects (polylines, polygons) during the R-Tree traversal (i.e. during query(...)) turned out to be quite computationally expensive (in my case, where the polylines/polygons have a lot of points).
Therefore, as a significantly faster solution I implemented a two-step algorithm: in the first step it finds k-nearest neighbors based on the bounding boxes stored in the R-Tree. The k-th neighbor will provide a distance d, which in the second step will be used for a range query, again, over the bounding boxes.
Hence, the costly distance between the query point and a polyline/polygon is computed only for k objects between the two queries and then for the results of the range query and during the tree traversal, only the cheap point-to-box distance is used.
This solution guarantees finding the k-nearest objects, based on the fact that
distance(point-bbox) <= distance(point-object).
Below is simplified C++ code:
template<typename Type>
void queryKNN(const BoostPoint2d& p, uint32_t N,
              std::vector<std::pair<Type, double>>* result) {
    // 1. Find k-nearest neighbors in the R-Tree based on bounding boxes. With very high
    //    probability the found neighbors will NOT be the real closest ones. This step is
    //    necessary to get an approximate searching radius for the subsequent range search.
    std::vector<RTreeValue> tempObjs;
    // queryFilter can filter out objects based on their ID.
    _index.rtree()->query(
            boost::geometry::index::nearest(p, N)
                    && boost::geometry::index::satisfies(queryFilter),
            std::back_inserter(tempObjs));

    // 2. Get the "true" distance from the farthest object.
    //    True distance is defined as the distance from the query point to the actual object
    //    geometry (rather than to the bounding box of the object).
    //    Because the distance calculation is computationally extensive, cache the distances.
    double maxDist = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tempObjs.size(); ++i) {
        const auto object = getObjectByIdFn(tempObjs[i].second);
        maxDist = std::max(maxDist, PointToLineDistance(p, object.polyline));
    }

    // 3. Based on the k-th object, create a search box for a range query and perform the query.
    const auto newBox = BoostBox(
            BoostPoint(p.x - maxDist - EPSILON_M, p.y - maxDist - EPSILON_M),
            BoostPoint(p.x + maxDist + EPSILON_M, p.y + maxDist + EPSILON_M));
    tempObjs.clear();
    _index.rtree()->query(
            boost::geometry::index::intersects(newBox), std::back_inserter(tempObjs));

    // 4. Get the k-nearest neighbors based on their true distance. Because the range query
    //    can return significantly higher number of objects than the requested number 'k', use
    //    a k-max heap for getting the neighbors (O(1) complexity).
    std::vector<std::pair<FeatureId, double>> idDistArray;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tempObjs.size(); ++i) {
        const auto id = tempObjs[i].second;
        const double distance = PointToLineDistance(p, getObjectByIdFn(id).line());
        auto item = std::make_pair(id, distance);
        if (idDistArray.size() < N) {
            idDistArray.push_back(item);
            std::push_heap(idDistArray.begin(), idDistArray.end(), heapComparator);
        } else if (distance < idDistArray[0].second) {
            std::pop_heap(idDistArray.begin(), idDistArray.end(), heapComparator);
            idDistArray.back() = item;
            std::push_heap(idDistArray.begin(), idDistArray.end(), heapComparator);
        }
    }

    // 5. Sort the max heap and copy the values to the final output array.
    std::sort_heap(idDistArray.begin(), idDistArray.end(), heapComparator);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < idDistArray.size(); ++i) {
        result->push_back(
            std::make_pair(getObjectByIdFn(idDistArray[i].first), idDistArray[i].second));
    }
}

